# Can I force CSS to load an image with Media Queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

here my css:

```css
html {
    background: url(../img/header_mobile.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html {
        background: url(../img/header_tablet.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

If my screen is bigger than 768px, my browser load header_tablet.jpg only
[image]
Can I force my browser to load header_mobile.jpg before with media queries ?

**edit:** for know what I'm doing is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("load", function () {
        if ($("html").width() > 767) {
            $('html').css('background-image', 'url({{ site.url }}/img/header_tablet.jpg)');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I try to find a media queries solution. on mobile load only my small picture. On tablet start to load my mobile image and load my big image.

Comment: so if the screen is wider than 768px, you want the browser to load header_tablet.jpg AND header_mobile.jpg?  I'm confused on what you are looking for.

Comment: You can use another hidden element with that background so it will load in the meanwhile. Or use JS when the document's ready to load it.

Comment: @andi yes I want my browser to load header_mobile.jpg (because my image is 10 times smaller) and header_tablet.jpg

Comment: But why would you want to do that?

Comment: what do you want your browser to do with header_mobile?  just preload it until you use it for something else?  Or did you want to display it somehow?

Comment: @andi I want to see my image instantly (so I create a 50ko jpeg header_mobile.jpg) Even if it pixelised, I don't care. For know i'm using a jquery code, waiting my big image to be fully loaded (header_tablet.jpg).And I replace my html background image. I'm asking if I can do the same with css.

Comment: Wouldn't `header_tablet.jpg` do the trick automagically if it is progressive JPEG? I doubt if extra HTTP request is the right solution in this case.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn it's a good alternative solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Pick a method.

1. HTML

   ```
   <img src="img/header_mobile.jpg" width=0 height=0 />
   ```
2. JavaScript

   ```
   img = new Image();
   img.src = "img/header_mobile.jpg";
   ```
3. CSS

   ```
   html:after {
       background: url(../img/header_mobile.jpg);
       opacity: 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: I changed it to setting width and height, because it was failing on IE10.  Now it seems to work on IE10, Firefox, and Chrome.  I can't say for earlier versions of IE.